# Как выбрать элемент из списка с помощью selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, testng

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выбрать элемент который находится внутри списка "select"? Пробовал использовать класс Select, но все равно вылетает исключение о том, что элемент не найден. Если не трудно, приведите пожалуйста пример работающего кода, в котором выбирается и кликается элемент раскрываемого списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML(пример):**

```
<select id="variants">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**Код:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

...

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
...

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("variants")));
select.selectByVisiableText("Two"); // выбирает option = Two по тексту
select.selectByIndex(2);            // выбирает option = Two по значению
```

[Источник](https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь написать себе небольшую функцию которая будет резать строку по определенному элементу и писать итог в массив, а потом от туда доставать любой элемент